# Teradata, Update single row if target has duplicate rows

Tags: teradata

[image]I want to update single row in target table if target has two duplicate rows.

```
target table
Employee_Id Join_date   Status  Eartned_points  used_vocher_cnt
123         02/01/2021    A         50           null
123         02/01/2021    A         40           null
source table
Employee_Id Join_date   Status  used_vocher_cnt
123          02/01/2021     A     4
```

There are two rows in target table and only one row has to be update with used_vocher_cnt 4
(either of the row) i.e total used vochers used by employee is 4.

```
   UPDATE TGT
    FROM (
          SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, 
          JOIN_DATE,
          STATUS, 
          USED_VOCHER_CNT
          FROM TARGET_TABLE
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Employee_id,Join_date,Status ORDER BY Eartned_points DESC)=1
       )TGT,
     SOURCE_TABLE  SRC
    SET Used_vocher_cnt=SRC.used_vocher_cnt
    WHERE SRC.Join_date=TGT.Join_date
    AND SRC.EMPLOYEE_ID=TGT.EMPLOYEE_ID
    AND SRC.Status=TGT.Status;
```

Error: derived table not allowed for update

Comment: What is the primary key column of the target table?

Comment: EMPLOYEE_ID, 
          JOIN_DATE,
          STATUS,

Comment: No, that's not a primary key, because 2 records in the target table have the same values for these 3 columns.  You need a unique column in the target table to do this update reliably.

Comment: I know that is not primary key.. first three columns  are primary index columns and target can have duplicate rows with primary index combination. If the target has unique primary index then given my update statement will work.. I am look for solution to update single row in target table

Comment: Primary index isn't relevant here.  Your update logic has to use every column that is used to make a row unique.  It sounds to me like either your table design or your update logic is flawed.  Or both.

Comment: Can't be done as just a simple UPDATE. You could copy just the matching rows to a work table with an added column (e.g. using ROW_NUMBER) to make them unique. Then update one of each group of rows in the work table (using that added column as part of the qualification), then delete all the matching rows from the original table and (re)insert the rows from the work table.